# Zend throw 404 headers in development mode

Tags: php, jquery, zend-framework

So I'm working on an application and I do some ajax calls to a controller, and in case of no data throws a 404.

```
throw new Zend_Controller_Action_Exception('This page does not exist', 404);
```

The problem is that I have `$this->frontController->throwExceptions(true);` so in development mode throws an error, but it doesn't set a 404 header, and I need the header because In the ajax call based on the header I know what's next.

Is there a way to throw a 404 header in dev mode with `throwExceptions` set to `true`?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ErrorHandler Plugin and register an ErrorController to indicate a 404 Page, as described here:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.plugins.html#zend.controller.plugins.standard.errorhandler

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to call: `->sendHeaders();`

```
$this->getResponse()-> setHttpResponseCode(405)-> setRawHeader('HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed')->sendHeaders();
```